# pre-typed commands while opening anaconda prompt (miniconda3)

Tags: python, conda, miniconda, openblas

I am currently trying to build OpenBLAS on my machine. For it, I am following [this](https://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS/wiki/How-to-use-OpenBLAS-in-Microsoft-Visual-Studio).

After downloading miniconda, I followed the steps given there (which are not resulting in a successful build), but now after opening the Anaconda Prompt, I always see this.

```
C:\Users\a>set "_LIB="

C:\Users\a>set "_CPATH="

C:\Users\a>if "C:\Users\a\miniconda3" == "" set "LIB=;\Library\lib"

C:\Users\a>if "C:\Users\a\miniconda3" == "" set "CPATH=;\Library\include"

C:\Users\a>if not "C:\Users\a\miniconda3" == "" set "LIB=;C:\Users\a\miniconda3\Library\lib"

C:\Users\a>if not "C:\Users\a\miniconda3" == "" set "CPATH=;C:\Users\a\miniconda3\Library\include"
```

What does this error signify? What can be done to solve it?

Comment: What makes you think it's an error?

Comment: Well, as I said, I am unable to build OpenBLAS, running into weird errors. While conversing with the maintainer of the project, he said he has no idea why the problems are occurring. So I thought this might be the cause of it.

Comment: You aren't showing the failing steps of the build process though.

Comment: How did you install/setup Conda?

Comment: Yeah, now the issues with the build are solved.